# How to hold a reference to a field in VB?

Tags: vb.net

In VB, I have a class that does some standard validations. What I'd LIKE to do is to declare some variables, then create instances of a validator class that include pointers to the variables, and then at some later time execute the validators to test the values in the fields that are pointed to.

Something like this:

```
public class MyData
  public property foo as string
  public property bar as string

  dim vfoo as validator
  dim vbar as validator

  public sub new()
    vfoo=new validator(&foo) ' i.e. & operator like in C
    vbar=new validator(&bar)
  end sub

  public sub validate()
    vfoo.validate
    vbar.validate
  end sub       
end class

public class validator
  dim _field as string* ' i.e. * like in C
  public sub new(field as string*)
    _field=field
  end sub

  public sub validate
    if string.isnullorempty(_field) then
      throw SomeException
    else if not SomeOtherTest(_field) then
      throw SomeOtherException
  end sub
```

The catch is that, to the best of my knowledge, there is nothing like C pointers in VB. Is there any reasonably easy way to do this?

At present I am passing in the field values at the time I call the validate() function, but this is not ideal because I would like to be able to create a List of validators specific to a given caller, and then loop through the List. But at the time I loop, how would I know which value from MyClass to pass in, unless I had a giant select statement keying off some "field code"? (And of course in real life, there are not just two fields like in this example, there are quite a few.)

Am I just having a brain freeze and there's an easy way to do this? Or can this not be done in VB because there are no such thing as pointers?

Comment: A pointer just isn't that useful, won't work on a property and surely your validator ought to generate a descriptive and actionable exception. Consider reflection, a FieldInfo or PropertyInfo can get the job done.

Comment: "generate a descriptive and actionable exception" Sure, the point of my question wasn't the content of the exception but how to generate it. Can you explain what you mean by "a FieldInfo or PropertyInfo"?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/programming-guide/concepts/reflection

Comment: There are a number of directions you can go to make something like this work.  Some alternatives to consider are custom attributes (you can then reflect on the type to identify all of the fields or properties with a particular attribute) or use of Expressions to get a sort of a design-time binding to a property.

Answer (score 1):

Like Java, VB doesn't make direct use of pointers (it compensates where it can with library/framework calls). In the context of a garbage-collected language, I can't imagine that this style of validation would work out well.

But for fun, maybe a lambda-based solution could suit?:

```
    Public Class MyData
        Public Property foo As String
        Public Property bar As String

        Dim vfoo As validator
        Dim vbar As validator

        Public Sub New()
            vfoo = New validator(Function() foo)
            vbar = New validator(Function() bar)
        End Sub

        Public Sub validate()
            vfoo.validate()
            vbar.validate()
        End Sub
    End Class

    Public Class validator
        ReadOnly _fieldFunc As Func(Of String)
        Public Sub New(fieldFunc As Func(Of String))
            _fieldFunc = fieldFunc
        End Sub

        Public Sub validate()
            Dim _field = _fieldFunc()
            If String.IsNullOrEmpty(_field) Then
                Throw New Exception("NullOrEmpty")
            ElseIf Not SomeOtherTest(_field) Then
                Throw New Exception("SomeOtherTest")
            End If
        End Sub

        Public Function SomeOtherTest(f As String) As Boolean
            Return True
        End Function

    End Class
```